# Teamcity reports tests passed twice

Tags: testing, teamcity

When I report my tests using TeamCity tools (using TeamCity Service Messages, via standard output from a .bat script file to be exact, echo commmand) I get as result the fact, that my test was passed twice, and all that I do is reading the file "test.log" with the following content (for example):

```
##teamcity[testStarted name='5013']
##teamcity[testFinished name='5013']
```

with my run.bat file with the following content:

```
@for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("test.log") do (
echo %%~a
)
```

Technically I have only 1 test. Wasn't it supposed to tell me that it has passed? Instead TeamCity says that it has passed 2 tests with the same names (5013).

Another example. A test.log file that looks like this

```
##teamcity[message text='Error!' errorDetails='52D4: ERROR CODE = 257' status='ERROR']
##teamcity[testSuiteStarted name='Autotests']
##teamcity[testStarted name='5013']
##teamcity[testFinished name='5013']
##teamcity[testStarted name='501E']
##teamcity[testFinished name='501E']
##teamcity[testStarted name='5052']
##teamcity[testFinished name='5052']
##teamcity[testStarted name='5169']
##teamcity[testFinished name='5169']
##teamcity[testStarted name='5251']
##teamcity[testFinished name='5251']
##teamcity[testStarted name='52D4']
##teamcity[testFailed name='52D4']
##teamcity[testFinished name='52D4']
##teamcity[testStarted name='5E00']
##teamcity[testFinished name='5E00']
##teamcity[testSuiteFinished name='Autotests']
```

It has 7 tests exactly, 1 of them failed. teamCity says that 1 test failed (**52D4**), and 13 passed successfuly.

This is how it looks in TeamCity WEB UI:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPDru.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What output you want to achieve?

Comment: TeamCity says that my build had passed 2 tests, when there is only one test that puts on a build. It might be confusing for a notification-receiver (via e-mail for example). And when I process a log with 7 tests total, and 1 of them failed, I get a result, as 1 test was failed, and 13 passed.

Comment: How the failed test looks in the log?

Comment: Thank you for you interest.. I just added an another example of a log file which contains one failed test, please see the post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i figured what was the problem... 
I simply had to add a `@` before the `echo` line...

i.e. `@echo %%~a`

Sorry for bothering